# Updating and Reading Cookies Dynamically

Tags: jquery

When I update a cookie value using jQuery, is there a way to read the new value without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 1):

Put your update cookie logic into a .js file then load and execute it using: [`getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) method.

> **Description of .getScript():** Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.